# Help with path-Integral (Complex Analysis)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I seem to be stuck on one path-integral and want to make sure how to solve it properly. As I have seen a lot of different solutions, maybe someone can give me some clarity

[image: The Question]

Part (a) is clear. Here I do not seem to have any problems. However after that,
I get into some troubles solving the first Integral. This is what I tried. I am not sure if I did it totally wrong

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Your earlier questions show that you're familiar with MathJax, so could you please type up your work in MathJax? (And maybe even the question statement too?) That would make it much easier for everyone to tell where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: Well I am really slow that's why. But if it's not readable I can do it.

Comment: Understandable -- everyone starts out typing MathJax painfully slowly, myself included. I'm fully aware of how cliche this sounds, but the only way to get better is to practice. Your work certainly isn't unreadable, but it would look better in MathJax. On an unrelated note, I'm not sure the problem you're having has to do with your substitution. If you were to change the bounds and keep things in terms of $u$, you'd end up with $\left[\frac12\ln u\right]_0^1$, which isn't any better.